# Sending email from own server to the internets

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I have set up an email server on my host. It's basically a SMTP server that listens on port 25.

```
const recvServer = new SMTPServer({
  requireTLS: true,
  authOptional: true,
  logger: true,      
  onConnect(session, callback) {
    return callback();
  },

  onMailFrom(address, session, callback) {
    console.log('from', address, session);
    return callback();
  },    

  onData(stream, session, callback) {
    console.log('new msg');
    let message = '';
    stream.on('data', chunk => {
      message += chunk;
    });

    stream.on('end', () => {

      callback(null, 'Message queued');
      simpleParser(message)
        .then(parsed => {
          console.log(parsed);
          // here I wish to forward the message to outside gmail addresses
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(ee)
        });

    });
  }    
});

recvServer.listen(25);

recvServer.on('error', err => {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

It works fine for receiving emails from outside, like gmail etc.

But I want to be able to send emails outside also, or forward emails that I receive to some gmail addresses.

I know that I can do that using Gmail SMTP servers, but then I need an gmail account and password.

I want to be able to send email with my own server, just like yahoo sends mail to gmail using their own server not gmail accounts :)

Comment: Note that if you want to send e-mails to a Gmail address, you need to authorize your server using SPF records, otherwise google will reject your e-mails.

Comment: Postfix works fine. If you have your server hosted by a third party, you can usually use their SMTP servers as relay

Comment: Alex - have you got your answer - if so please accept - if not please explain!

Answer (score 9):

You need a MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) in order to send an email.

So the popular options is: **Postfix**, here a guid how to setup postfix on ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Or you can spin up a docker container like: https://hub.docker.com/r/bytemark/smtp/

Then you can use `nodemailer` to send emails through postfix or docker instance.

And if you want there is a full stack docker image all batteries included: https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver

Comment: Please consider the exim (https://www.exim.org) MTA as well - it is very good, and easy to configure. Created by Uni. Cambridge!

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can use [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) for sending emails.

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main(){

  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
  let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: testAccount.pass // generated ethereal password
    }
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: "bar@example.com, baz@example.com", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>" // html body
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
  // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

  // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sohail mentioned in the above answer you can use NodeMailer (https://nodemailer.com/about/) and its fairly easy. Below is a simple code snippet of using it. In addition there are other services that provided free tiers if you are looking for fancier services(examples are SendGrid (https://sendgrid.com/)).

async function sendemail(email, host , email_body) {

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "mail.example.com.au",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: "test@example.com.au", // generated ethereal user
        pass: "email_password" // generated ethereal password
    }
});

let emailBody = email_body // This is the body of your email which is more or less a String


let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '" Name of sender" <test@example.com.au>', // sender address
    to: email, // list of receivers
    subject: "Email Subject", // Subject line
    text: emailBody, // plain text body
    // html:  // html body
});

console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to send email, you need an email client, not a server.  Writing the client is usually easier than writing the server, so you could do that.  If you don't want to write your own, you could use an MTA (like Postfix), which will contain both a client and a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this function by creating an account in [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) and then using its Node.js api to send emails.

These are the steps:-

```
npm install @sendgrid/mail
```

And then use this following code snippet :-

```
const mailer = require('@sendgrid/mail');
mailer.setApiKey(<YOUR_SENDGRID_API_KEY>);
const message = {
  to: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  from: 'abc@gmail.com',
  subject: 'hello world',
  text: 'hello world'
};
mailer.send(message);
```

You can get more samples and documentation in their [Github repo](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs).